# How to handle Core Data model versioning in team environments with multiple branches

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, git-flow

I'm looking for a general process for handling model changes in team environments, specifically where a branching model like Git Flow is used. I want to use lightweight migration, but I'm concerned how this works if multiple developers are versioning within their branches.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to version only when changes need to be made to the model, rather than pre-emptively.

When working with a team, I'd recommend whomever needs to make model changes to check with the other members of the team that it is ok to version the model, primarily checking if the model had already been versioned. If it hadn't been versioned yet, then I'd have the dev issue a pull request to develop for just the model version bump. Once that is merged, then anyone who needs to make changes to the model for the next release can pull the newly versioned model from develop and make their changes on that new version. Merging changes from different developers on different branches to the same model has not in my experience been a difficult process.

With all of this, I'm thinking only of lightweight migration, which in most cases is likely all you will need. For manual migrations, which are likely going to be rare, I'd recommend taking a more ad hoc approach that satisfies the particular needs of the project.

Comment: Generally I agree with this. I think the pre-emptive (per release) approach is more beneficial where there are frequent model changes and more than a few devs on the team.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I think the best approach is to **version the model once per release**.

Generally,

### In case of early development (pre-release)

No need for versioning (and therefore migration) as this would just slow down development. Devs and QA will just need to reinstall the app for every model change.

### Once the app is ready for release

At the beginning of every release, i.e. when the release branch is created, the lead developer should create a new data model version on the develop branch. This will allow multiple devs to make changes on feature branches without the need to coordinate (i.e. "who's going to version the model? and how are we going to get that into our branches?").

### Data model changes on the release branch are discouraged

This will likely break the migration path from the previous release.